# icecast make a post request on meta data update

Tags: icecast

I have an icecast server that gets metadata updates from an external source. What's the best way to make a post request to another server when ICECAST metadata is updated?

I want to take the updated metadata and send it to a 3rd party server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [playlist.log](http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/config-file.html#log). It gets each metadata update including the number of listeners at that time on that mountpoint.

If you need more details you can plug into [URL-authentication of listener clients and source clients](https://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/auth.html#url). Those fire upon e.g. listener connections or in case of legacy sources also on metadata updates.